# What is `threads` in the source panel

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Today I encountered `threads` section under `Watch` and `Call stack` sections in `Sources` panel. Now I'm trying to find it and it's not there. What is it for? Why is not shown for all websites?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's there when the page you're looking is using Web Workers to run multiple threads. (Try it [on this demo page](http://html5demos.com/worker).)

[image]

It allows you to select which thread to debug.

For example, you can pause in execution in multiple threads at the same time. When you click on each thread the call stack etc. are updated to show the information for that thread.

Comment: The demo worker on the html5demo has some network error, which will fail to see the `Thread`. Maybe u could change it to a more reliable one, e.g. [this demo](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webworker)